# Databricks not saving dataframes as Parquet properly in the blob storage

Tags: python, azure, blob, databricks, parquet

I am using Databricks with a mounted blob storage. When I execute my Python notebook which creates large pandas DataFrame and tries to store them as .parquet files they show up having 0 bytes.

The saving takes place in a submodule that I import and not in the main notebook itself. The strange this is that saving the dataframe as a parquet file always stores it as an empty file, i.e. with 0 bytes. However, if I try to save a dataframe as a .parquet file in the main notebook itself, it works.

The problem seems to be very similar to this issue: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y00009MIWkfSAH/how-can-i-save-a-parquet-file-using-pandas-with-a-data-factory-orchestrated-notebook

I have installed both pyarrow and pandas and try to save a dataframe as follows:

```py
df.to_parquet("blob storage location.parquet", index=False, engine="pyarrow")
```

Everything works fine locally but running this in Databricks is causing issues. I first tried to save my dataframes as HDF5 files, but the saving process doesn't work in Databricks it seems. I then switched to Parquet but I am running into the issue mentioned below.

Does anyone have a solution or an explanation as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got below results**:

*This is my sample mount location path `/mnt/io243`*

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container_Name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_name>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net":"Access_key"})
```

[image]

> NOTE : As you can see, this is my mount path `/mnt/io243`.If I used
> the same mount path without adding `/dbfs` it stores as an empty file.
> So Use mount path like this **Syntax
> :**`/dbfs/mnt/io243/<file_name>.parquet` .Make sure to install fsspec
> use this command `%pip install fsspec`.

*I successfully got the file into the destination location using the below code.*

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

import pandas as pd
#%pip install fsspec

#sample datafram
my_data = [
            ("vamsi","1","M",2000),
            ("saideep","2","M",3000),
            ("rakesh","3","M",4000)
          ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=my_data,schema=schema)

df1 = df.toPandas()

df1.to_parquet("/dbfs/mnt/io243/def1.parquet",index=False, engine="pyarrow")
```

[image]

*Yes, You can check whether inside mount location file is stored or not. Please follow this code.*

```
dbutils.fs.ls('<mount_path>')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation but in the end I doubt this would have solved my issue. Using fastparquet as the engine already solved the issue for me.

Comment: As commented, you may mark it is as answer. Doing so useful to other community members.